# Generic parent and child and Incompatible types for parent fileds

Tags: java, generics

I have simple generic parent class and suppose I have a list in this class:

```
public class GenericParent<N extends Number> {
protected List<String> s;
}
```

And also I have a child class that extend from this class like this:

```
public class GenericChild extends GenericParent {

    private void testMethod() {
        for (String o : s) {
            //.....
        }
    }
}
```

I get Incompatible types in this line `for (String o : s)` and tell me that `s` is not String, it is object. but if I define my child class like this `public class GenericChild extends GenericParent<Integer>` and declare my generic type, error goes away. Why this happened?
My question is not about what is the raw type and generic class. I define List of String in class that have generic type of Number and I don't get it why in child class I can't use my list of String that defined in parent.

Comment: GenericParent is a raw type. References to generic type GenericParent<N> should be parameterized. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: When a raw type is used, the constructors, instance methods and non-static fields are also erased.

Comment: @JYun I don't get it. Could you please explain me more?

Comment: I use independent field type from what parent class get. Generic type for class is Number and my field is list of String. These to type is completely different from each other.

Comment: Yes, but if you read to the part about type erasure for non-static fields in my link, it explains it

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much